# QStateMachine with RestoreProperty is losing property on transition

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qstatemachine

The Qt documentation for State machines shows two principles I'm using: [Restoring Properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/statemachine-api.html#using-restore-policy-to-automatically-restore-properties) and [Targetless transitions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/statemachine-api.html#targetless-transitions). The first allows to assign properties to a QState, the second to trigger events only in a specific state.

When I combine both functions, restoring properties is not working anymore. When a `QSignalTransition` is fired, the properties are set to their initial values (before the state machine was started), even if the current state is not left.

I have a short example to reproduce this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QStateMachine>
#include <QSignalTransition>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc,argv);
  QWidget *w = new QWidget;

  QStateMachine *machine = new QStateMachine(w);
  QState *s1 = new QState;
  QState *s2 = new QState;

  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(w);
  QPushButton *btnState = new QPushButton("Not set");
  QPushButton *btnTrigger = new QPushButton("Trigger");
  layout->addWidget(btnState);
  layout->addWidget(btnTrigger);

  machine->setGlobalRestorePolicy(QStateMachine::RestoreProperties);

  s1->assignProperty(btnState,"text","S1");
  s2->assignProperty(btnState,"text","S2");

  s1->addTransition(btnState,SIGNAL(clicked()),s2);
  s2->addTransition(btnState,SIGNAL(clicked()),s1);

  QSignalTransition *sig = new QSignalTransition(btnTrigger,SIGNAL(clicked()));
  s1->addTransition(sig);

  machine->addState(s1);
  machine->addState(s2);
  machine->setInitialState(s1);

  machine ->start();

  w->show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

It has two buttons: The state button toggles between S1 and S2, the trigger button triggers a QSignalTransition when S1 is active. Clicking trigger when S1 is active, the button text will be set back to `"Not set"`. If I understood the concept of `setGlobalRestorePolicy()` correctly, the property should stay `"S1"`, as it is the value of the state S1, and the state was not left and is still active.

Is there something I missed or misunderstood, or did I something wrong?

I'm using Qt 4.8.4 on windows, if this makes any difference.